# Reading in variables from a text file and creating a table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays, vbscript

I have this code

```
'Open a file for reading
'Get a StreamReader class that can be used to read the file
Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
Dim variableArray(20) As String
objStreamReader = File.OpenText(filePath)

'Read one line at a time
Dim someString As String
Dim variableNum As Integer = 0
'Iterate through lines
While objStreamReader.Peek() <> -1
    someString = objStreamReader.ReadLine()
    variableArray(variableNum) = someString
    variableNum = variableNum + 1
End While
For Each line As String In variableArray

Next
objStreamReader.Close()
```

I have a vbscript that is outputting results in a log file, appended on each line and delimited by a "|" there will only be two columns.

Here is a snippet of the VBScript code

```
f1.WriteLine("Server Name " & "|" & strName)
f1.WriteLine("OS Name: " & "|" & strCaption)
f1.WriteLine("OS Version: " & "|" & strVersion
f1.WriteLine("CSD Version: " & "|" & strCSDVer
f1.WriteLine("Serial Number: " & "|" & strSerial
```

How can I get the For Each part of my code to read this, break it apart and then create a table showing the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you need two values from the variableArray in order to add a new row to the table, I would do a For..Next Loop (stepping by 2) instead of a For...Each:

```
Dim myTable As New Table
Dim loopCount As Integer

For loopCount = 0 To variableNum Step 2

    Dim myRow As New TableRow
    Dim myCell1 As New TableCell
    Dim myCell2 As New TableCell

    myCell1.Text = variableArray(loopCount)
    myCell2.Text = variableArray(loopCount + 1)
    myRow.Cells.Add(myCell1)
    myRow.Cells.Add(myCell2)
    myTable.Rows.Add(myRow)

Next
```

Since you already have the amount of elements in your array stored in "variableNum", you can just loop from 0 to that value, stepping by 2.  Each iteration you'll create two cells with the values of the current and next variables in the array.  Then, those cells will be added to a row, which will in turn be added to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a DataTable

```
Dim table As DataTable = new DataTable("MyTable")
```

Now Inside the Foreach:

```
Dim LineArray() As String = Split(line, "|") 'This will break apart each line into its two parts
'Now add each item of LineArray to the datatable. AKA
Dim column As DataColumn = new DataColumn()
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")
column.ColumnName = LineArray(0)
column.ReadOnly = True
column.Unique = True
table.Columns.Add(column)

Dim row As DataRow 
row = table.NewRow()
row(LineArray(0)) = LineArray(1)
table.Rows.Add(row)
```

I don't know the entire piece of logic that you're trying to implement but that should give you a good start.  It's basically taking the first column and setting it as a Column within the table and then taking the second column and making that a row value.

Once you've constructed your DataTable you can bind it to a GridView which in an HTML sense is a table.

Hope this helps.